# failed [object ErrorEvent] - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a negative test case for a specific `get` function in an adapter service that requests data from a server and responds accordingly. The function sends an `http get` request to the server, which returns the specified data required. For this, I create a mock request to the backend using the `HttpTestingController`. So far I have been able to complete the most obvious test case: return a 200/OK status and display some information to the user.

When I come to the negative test cases however, I'm trying to use `ErrorEvent` to create the error from the backend. However, when I run the test, it gives me an error **jasmine Failed: [object ErrorEvent]**. I understand there have been many similar cases for different users, many of which have been solved when they use `--source-map=false` , but for me even applying that does nothing but show the same error and a stack trace with it. I have been trying to figure this out for a while but don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Please see the second `get` test in **adapter.service.spec.ts**

**Note**: I'm using typescript 2.9.1 and angular 6.0.8 for the application

Here are the files that I'm working with for the tests:

**adapter.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import {
  HttpHeaders,
    HttpClient,
    HttpParams,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Request, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtService } from '../jwt/jwt.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../logger/logger.service';

const API_URL = environment.api.host;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdapterService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private jwtService: JwtService,
              private logger: LoggerService) {}
  /**
   * This method logs the errors if the API call fails.
   *
   * @param self
   * @method formatErrors
   * @return
   */
   private formatErrors(error: any) {
     return  throwError(error.error);
   }
  /**
   * This method adds the headers to the API requests.
   *
   * @param path
   * @method requestHeaders
   * @return
   */
    private requestHeaders(path: string) {
    let headers;
    if (path !== 'outh2/token') {
        headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Accept':  'application/json',
          'Oauth-Token': this.jwtService.getToken()
        })
      }
        return headers;
    }
  /**
   * This method generates the GET api call.
   *
   * @param path
   * @param params
   * @method get
   * @return
   */
    get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable < any > {
    let headers = this.requestHeaders(path);
        return this.http.get(`${API_URL}${path}`, { headers })
            .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }
  /**
   * This method generates the PUT api call.
   *
   * @param path
   * @param body
   * @method put
   * @return
   */
    put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable < any > {
        return this.http.put(
            `${API_URL}${path}`,
            JSON.stringify(body),
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }
  /**
   * This method generates the POST api call.
   *
   * @param path
   * @param body
   * @method post
   * @return
   */
    post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable < any > {
    return this.http.post(
            `${API_URL}${path}`,
            JSON.stringify(body),
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }
  /**
   * This method generates the DELETE api call.
   *
   * @param path
   * @method delete
   * @return
   */
    delete(path): Observable < any > {
    return this.http.delete(
            `${API_URL}${path}`,
        ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }
}
```

**adapter.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpRequest, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

const API_URL = environment.api.host;
var PATH = 'somePATH';

import { AdapterService } from './adapter.service';

describe('AdapterService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        AdapterService
      ]
    });
  });

  afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (backend: HttpTestingController) => {
    backend.verify();
  }));

  //test case for GET
  it('Send a valid GET request to the server', async(inject([AdapterService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdapterService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      let response = { "data": "answer" };
      service.get(PATH).subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toEqual(response);
      });
      backend.expectOne(API_URL + PATH).flush({ "data": "answer" }, { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
    })));

//THIS IS THE TEST CASE NOT WORKING FOR ME
  it('Use an invalid or non existent URL to send the GET request', async(inject([AdapterService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdapterService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      service.get(PATH).subscribe((next: any) => {
        expect(next.failure.error.type).toBe("URL not found!");
      });
      let responseFromServer = backend.expectOne(API_URL+PATH);
      responseFromServer.error(new ErrorEvent("URL not found!"));
    })));

  //test case for POST
  it('should send a valid POST request', async(inject([AdapterService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdapterService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      let data = { 'name': 'Admin', "class": "Superior" };
      service.post(PATH, data).subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toBeNull();
      });
      backend.expectOne(API_URL + PATH, JSON.stringify(data)).flush(null, { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
    })));

  //test case for PUT
  it('should send a valid PUT request', async(inject([AdapterService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdapterService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      let data = { 'name': 'MEME', "class": "NONE" };
      service.put(PATH, data).subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toBeTruthy();
      });
      backend.expectOne(API_URL + PATH, JSON.stringify(data)).flush(1, { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
    })));

  //test case for DELETE
  it('should send a valid DELETE request', async(inject([AdapterService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: AdapterService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      PATH = PATH + '/132';
      service.delete(PATH).subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toBeTruthy();
      });
      backend.expectOne(API_URL + PATH).flush(1, { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
    })));


});
```

**The error that I get on chrome**

```
Error: Failed: [object ErrorEvent]
    at stack (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:2338:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:2308:14)
    at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:858:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:487:34)
    at Env.fail (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:1286:25)
    at Function.next.fail (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/www/html/employee_portal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?73bc53d3671677e6a093fc74e4f9bcde57e5f7ad:4272:19)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:779:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:834:21)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:287:39)
```

Comment: what do you see in your chrome dev tool ?

Comment: The console is completely blank, there are no traces of an object being formed anywhere or any error being invoked for that matter

Comment: @billyjov it may be possible to reproduce the error using just these files (along with adding a few properties in environment.js)